# Applying media queries so that it can work in all space geometries

Tags: android, css, html, media-queries

I wrote a `HTML5, CSS` and `javascript` code and used phonegap to get apk. However I'm not getting the exact screen in mobile which is same as web version. Here is the screen shot:
[image: Website]
And here is the code which I used:
`HTML`

```
<div><p><center style="color: #fff;">PRESS THE BUTTON AND PUT YOUR THOUGHTS IN RESPECTIVE BOX.</center><p><div>
<image src="past.png" style="position: absolute; left: 238px; margin: 76px;"></image>
<image src="present.png" style="margin: 76px; position: absolute; left: 535px;"></image>
<image src="future.png" style="margin: 76px; position: absolute; right: 205px;"></image>
<image src="box.png" style="margin: 259px; left: 75px; position: absolute;"></image>
<image src="box1.png" style="margin: 258px; position: absolute; left: 377px;"></image>
<image src="box2.png" style="margin: 258px; position: absolute; right: 44px;"></image>
<br style="clear: both" />
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="newBall(0);"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="newBall(1);"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="newBall(2);"></canvas>
```

`CSS`

```
#myCanvas1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 144px;
}
#myCanvas2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 453px;
}
#myCanvas3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 113px;
}
#myCanvas1, #myCanvas2, #myCanvas3 {
    margin: 181px;
}
body {
    background-image: url('hero.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover;
    /*-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;*/
}

/*media queries*/
@media screen and (max-device-height: 5px) {
    #myCanvas1, #myCanvas2, #myCanvas3 {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #myCanvas1 {
        left: 120px;
    }
    #myCanvas2 {
        left: 429px;
    }
    #myCanvas3 {
        left: 79px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 280px) and (max-device-width: 1200px) {
    div {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #img1 {
        left: 123px;
    }
    #img2 {
        left: 421px;
    }
    #img3 {
        right: 102px;
    }
    #img4 {
        left: 12px;
    }
    #img5 {
        left: 168px;
    }
    #img6 {
        right: 12px;
    }
    #img1, #img2, #img3 {
        margin: 38px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #img4, #img5, #img6 {
        margin: 180px;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

But the media rules which I set up aren't working. I want the app to be opened in landscape mode with same screen as in web version.

Comment: use like this: @media screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 1200px) {}

Comment: open your page in chrome browser then right click on page with inspect element then select Toggle device mode(bottom left most side) and select your device here...you can see which width is applying in device....

Comment: Okay, I want background image to be fitted in mobile screen, how can I do that?

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width:320px){
  body{background:#FFF url('../img/screen_320-480.png') no-repeat left top;} 
} it is only example you can add your device size.

Comment: like another device : @media screen and (max-width: 540px){
 body{background:#FFF url('../img/screen_540-888.png') no-repeat left top;}